# problem with QProcess whitspaces and arguments

Tags: c++, qt, process, path, arguments

I want to call an executable via a QProcess. The path to the executable can contain whitespaces. Therefore I put quotations around the path to the executable.

However, this only works as long as I do not add any arguments.

The following code reproduces the problem:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0; // no whitespace, no argument -> works
    //    int i = 1; // whitespace with quotation, no arguments -> works
    //    int i = 2; // no whitespace, arguments -> works
    //    int i = 3; // whitespace with quotation, arguments -> works not

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess *process = new QProcess();

    QString pathToFile;
    QString absolutePathToProgram;
    pathToFile = "/home/user/tmp/file.xml";

    if (i == 0){
        absolutePathToProgram = "/home/user/tmp/executable";
    }else if(i == 1){
        absolutePathToProgram = "/home/user/tmp whitespace/executable";
        absolutePathToProgram = "\"" + absolutePathToProgram + "\"";
    }else if(i == 2){
        absolutePathToProgram = "/home/user/tmp/executable";
    }else if(i == 3){
        absolutePathToProgram = "/home/user/tmp whitespace/executable";
        absolutePathToProgram = "\"" + absolutePathToProgram + "\"";
    }

    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << pathToFile;

    if (i==0 || i==1){
        process->start(absolutePathToProgram);
    }else{
        process->start(absolutePathToProgram,arguments);
    }

    process->waitForFinished();

    QString output(process->readAllStandardOutput());

    qDebug() << output;

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have added 4 cases:

- `i == 0`: path to executable does not contain whitespaces and we do not pass arguments. This works
- `i == 1`: path to executable does contain whitespaces and we do not pass arguments. This works
- `i == 2`: path to executable does not contain whitespaces and we do pass arguments. This works
- `i == 3`: path to executable does contain whitespaces and we do pass arguments. This does not work

**Why is case `i == 3` not working?**

I'm using Ubuntu as an operating system.

**BONUS:**

I also need to get it working on Windows. Usually, on Windows, I start the program with:

```
process->start("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/c" << absolutePathToProgram << pathToFile);
```

I didn't have the time to test it on windows but if someone posts an answer and also knows how to create a solution on windows please let me know.

Comment: Mmm... process it's being executed for me (Windows 10 + Visual Studio 15.9.2 + Qt 5.10.0). What is exactly "not working"? Process not being launched? stdout not read?

Comment: Thanks for testing. I didn't test it with windows yet. On my Ubuntu it is not working. I'll add my gcc qt version tomorrow. My problem is, that the process is not launched. How exactly did you start your Process with windows (can you post your line of code `process->start()`)?

Comment: I modified your example, lines 29: `absolutePathToProgram = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe";` and 34: `arguments << "c:\\readme.md" << "-loadingTime";`. The rest was your same example.

Answer (score 0):

May be the static methods:

```
QDir::homePath()
QDir::toNativeSeparator(...)
```

can help you (for the cross portability too)

E.g.

```
const QString absolutePathToProgram = QDir::toNativeSeparators(QString("%1/QtExamples/tmp dir/my app").arg(QDir::homePath()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

I use this (in python)

maybe you can use regex for the shlex part

set paths that contains spaces in double quotes

import shlex

```
def run(self):
    cli = shlex.split(self.commandfield.text(), posix=False)
    cmd = str(cli[0]) ### is the executable
    if (QStandardPaths.findExecutable(cmd)):
        print("command", cmd,  "found")
        del cli[0] ### delete first value in list
        t = " ".join(cli)
        if self.process.state() != 2:
            self.process.waitForStarted()
            self.process.waitForFinished()
            self.process.start((cmd + " " + t))
            print("running", self.process.program(), self.process.arguments())
        else:
            print("error ...")
```

Comment: Just a note, OP asked for a C++ implementation; even though the regex could be applied, your answer is effectively not complete -> low quality. Consider updating it.